# How to make a user GUI to edit a variable within a function within a function?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a GUI so that users can edit/modify 'x1' or 'x2' etc  their own user input, as you can see in the code. My understanding is that those are variables of a function within a function. So I am finding it challenging to make the logical leap to the next step for this. Your advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance,
George

```
#Form filling mapping
import io

import pdfrw
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def run():
    canvas_data = get_overlay_canvas()
    form = merge(canvas_data, template_path='./SmartInvoice.pdf')
    save(form, filename='merged.pdf')


def get_overlay_canvas() -> io.BytesIO:
    data = io.BytesIO()
    pdf = canvas.Canvas(data)
    #Invoice issuer, company name etc:
    pdf.drawString(x=100, y=727, text='x1')
    #Issuer address
    pdf.drawString(x=100, y=711, text='x2')
    #ABN or ACN
    pdf.drawString(x=100, y=696, text='x3')
    #Phone Contact
    pdf.drawString(x=100, y=681, text='x4')
    #Invoice issued to:
    pdf.drawString(x=83, y=606, text='x5')
    #Customer Details:
    pdf.drawString(x=83, y=591, text='x6')
    #Tax Invoice No.
    pdf.drawString(x=535, y=674, text='x7')
    #Date of issuance of invoice
    pdf.drawString(x=516, y=658, text='x8')
    #Form Description
    pdf.drawString(x=33, y=650, text='x9')
    #Subtotal
    pdf.drawString(x=500, y=458, text='$1,000,000')
    #Subtotal 2
    pdf.drawString(x=500, y=400, text='$1,500,000')
    #Subtotal 3
    pdf.drawString(x=500, y=342, text='$4,000,000')
    #Total
    pdf.drawString(x=500, y=237, text='$6,500,000')
    #GST
    pdf.drawString(x=500, y=210, text='$715,000')
    #Total Inc. GST
    pdf.drawString(x=500, y=178, text='$7,150,000')
    #Description of good or service provided.
    pdf.drawString(x=45, y=465, text='x23')
    #Payment methods:
    pdf.drawString(x=150, y=120, text='x22')
    #Payment due by date:
    pdf.drawString(x=86, y=151, text='16/08/2018')
    pdf.save()
    data.seek(0)
    return data


def merge(overlay_canvas: io.BytesIO, template_path: str) -> io.BytesIO:
    template_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(template_path)
    overlay_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(overlay_canvas)
    for page, data in zip(template_pdf.pages, overlay_pdf.pages):
        overlay = pdfrw.PageMerge().add(data)[0]
        pdfrw.PageMerge(page).add(overlay).render()
    form = io.BytesIO()
    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(form, template_pdf)
    form.seek(0)
    return form


def save(form: io.BytesIO, filename: str):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(form.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: You can't "edit variables in a function in a function". You will have to store those values somewhere "outside" the function where a GUI could change them, and then pass them into the function whenever you call the function.

Comment: Thanks for the response - how would I store those values "outside" of the function? I think we're getting there.